# What is more compact, GET or POST?

Tags: http, post, get, webserver, data-transfer

Is POST more compact than GET, since GET requests have to be URL-encoded?

Comment: Why are you concerned with this optimization?

Comment: Away from optimizations, the question is very interesting indeed.

Comment: Use get to modify the view you present to a user. Use post to modify what is on your server. Don't mix them up, and use the correct one for the correct job. Gets should ALWAYS be side effect free.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a quick note: According to Yahoo YUI team and YSlow, when using XMLHttpRequest objects (AJAX), POST almost always uses two packets, while GET will use one (content length permitting).

This means that your AJAX requests are "more compact" if you use GET.

Source:

http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#ajax_get

Answer (score 5):

Both have completely different purposes, so I wouldn't compare them in that way. `GET` is for data retrieval, and should have no side effects beside that. And `POST` is for sending data, not retrieving them.

Answer (score 4):

So are POST. They're equally compact. It's a matter of *where* the data go. For POST it goes into request body. For GET — into URL itself. Moreover, in case of `multpart/form-data` encoding (which is required for file uploads, but in this case GET request is not an option, anyway) POST will be more verbose.

Answer (score 2):

No, POST requests still have to be put into the http query. You just don't see them as part of the URL.

IE here's a get query

```
  GET <url with params>
```

vs a post query

```
  POST <url>
  ...
  <params>
```

Answer (score 2):

POST has one more letter in it than GET, so it's less compact.

If compactness is very important and you don't care about HTTP semantics, use a binary protocol instead. The semantics of POST and GET are different, and HTTP is not optimised for compactness.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to review the following information regarding get vs post usability.
http://www.w3.org/2001/tag/doc/whenToUseGet.html

To sum it up:

**use GET if:**

The interaction is more like a question.  For example, lookups, read only operations, etc.

**use POST if:**

The interaction is more like an order, changes the state of a resource, or the user will be held accountable for the results of the interaction.

Note that none of this takes into account the SIZE of the request.  For more thought, you might consider the early days of the internet when search engines caused database problems simply by performing GET requests on the links they crawled.  This was because some programmers used GET requests to change the state of resources (such as deleting records, dropping tables, etc).

Comment: I would imagine that a fair number of web sites still mis-use GET to change state.